# What is the oldest non-biographical work of literature in which the author is also a protagonist?

Tags: history-of-literature, dante-alighieri, divine-comedy

Dante's [*Divine Comedy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy), written in the years 1308-1320, is a long narrative poem in which the poet is also a protagonist in the story. The story also includes many real characters, such as Virgil and many Florentines who had been involved in the struggle between [the Guelphs and the Ghibellines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guelphs_and_Ghibellines). However, it is obviously not an autobiographical work, since Dante's journey through hell, purgatory and paradise is not a real event.

This leads me to the question whether the *Divine Comedy* is the earliest work of literature in which the author is also a protagonist in the story. This should not be confused with works in which the protagonist is the narrator but not the historical author; [narrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative#Types_of_narrators_and_their_modes) and author are two different concepts. (I am also excluding philosophical dialogues from this question, otherwise [Plato's dialogues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato#Dialogues) might be a valid answer.)

Comment: "*Dante's journey through the hell, purgatory and paradise is not a real event.*" - `citation-needed` ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor In the *Divine Comedy*, [earth is spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_Earth#High_and_late_medieval_Europe) but the southern hemisphere is uninhabited. I'm sure the southern hemisphere was inhabited in the Middle Ages and that Virgil had been dead for a while ;-)

Answer (score 9):

As written, the most obvious answer would probably be a lyrical poet, writing in first person. [Sappho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sappho)'s poetry (ca 600 BCE) appears to be among the first in the Western tradition to use such a device. To what degree it is biographical can of course be debated.

The first writing that is definitely fiction is probably Lucian of Samosata's *[A True Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_True_Story)*, written in the second century CE. In it we can read about the fantastical travels of the narrator, who at one point erect a monument on which we can read that his name is "Lucian". He and his company travels beyond the Pillars of Hercules, are taken by a whirlwind to the Moon, witness a war between the forces of the Moon and those of the Sun, travel in the belly of a giant whale, go to the Islands of the Blessed and meet the heroes of the Trojan War. *A True Story* is often cited as the earliest science fiction novel, containing a lot of elements we recognize from modern offerings of the genre.

Comment: Interesting answer, especially if the so-called [Brothers Poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_Poem) can be attributed to Sappho. (The general difficulty with my question is: the older the author, the harder it will be to provide evidence that the protagonist also the author.)

Comment: Awesome response!